# How to use Convert.Int32() method in LINQ to Entities Join?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a problem with LINQ to Entities query, I am joining four tables but there two tables that don't have the same datatype for the join column below is the query.

```
var qry = (from i in dc.INTERNETDATAs
           join c in dc.COVERS on Convert.ToInt32(i.COVERTYPE) equals c.COV_TYPE
           join b in dc.BENEFITS on c.COVERID equals b.COVERID
           join p in dc.POLICies on i.REFERENCENO equals p.BACS_POLNO into grp
           where i.DATELOADED >= startDate
             && i.DATELOADED < endDate
             && i.CAMPAIGNTYPE == campaignType
             && c.COVERTYPEID == coverTypeId
           select i).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

In the code above the first join

```
join c in dc.COVERS on Convert.ToInt32(i.COVERTYPE) equals c.COV_TYPE
```

is giving following error

> InnerException: System.NotSupportedException
>          Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.
>          Source=System.Data.Entity

How can I achieve this?

Comment: this is not `LINQ to SQL`, it's `LINQ to Entity` - a part of `Entity Framework`

Comment: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Where is the `ToString()` call?

Comment: At first you say `Convert.ToInt32`, but the exception mentioned `ToString()`?

Comment: And what type COVERTYPE property has?

Comment: @Mitz As the error suggested `Linq-Entities` do not recognize this method **cannot be translated into a store expression** means Linq do not know how to change this as a `sql` variable , Its not supported in `Linq-Entities` .

Answer (score 3):

Assuming i.COVERTYPE is a string, avoid using Convert.ToInt32(). Use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` on *c.COV_TYPE* in stead. It's from `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`, and can be invoked like:

```
var qry = (from i in dc.INTERNETDATAs
           join c in dc.COVERS on i.COVERTYPE equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.COV_TYPE)
           join b in dc.BENEFITS on c.COVERID equals b.COVERID
           join p in dc.POLICies on i.REFERENCENO equals p.BACS_POLNO into grp
           where i.DATELOADED >= startDate
             && i.DATELOADED < endDate
             && i.CAMPAIGNTYPE == campaignType
             && c.COVERTYPEID == coverTypeId
           select i).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

Comment: even this is not working I have added the name space System.Data.Objects.SqlClient but I am not able to get this function.

Comment: @Mitz add `using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;`

Comment: using SqlFunctions.StringConvert here gives the following error The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double?)' and 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert(decimal?)' C:\ProjectsMitesh\PersonalAccident\Common\AvivaPAS.Repositories\InternetDataRepository.cs

Answer (score 0):

```
 var qry = (from i in dc.INTERNETDATAs
                       join c in dc.COVERS on ConvertID(i.COVERTYPE) equals c.COV_TYPE
                       join b in dc.BENEFITS on c.COVERID equals b.COVERID
                       join p in dc.POLICies on i.REFERENCENO equals p.BACS_POLNO into grp
                       where i.DATELOADED >= startDate
                         && i.DATELOADED < endDate
                         && i.CAMPAIGNTYPE == campaignType
                         && c.COVERTYPEID == coverTypeId
                       select i).DefaultIfEmpty();

            public int CheckId(string id)
                     {
                        Int32 CoverType=Convert.ToInt32(id);
                         return CoverType ;
                      }
```

**Linq to Entities** do not support `Convert.ToInt(system.string)` and is unable to convert it to a Sql datatype . Try to compare your two values using `SqlFunctions` or change your `datatype`.

Try converting both to `doubles for comparison purpose`.

Comment: using SqlFunctions.StringConvert here gives the following error The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double?)' and 'System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert(decimal?)' C:\Projects‌​Mitesh\PersonalAccident\Common\AvivaPAS.Repositories\InternetDataRepository.cs

Comment: Try converting both values to double for comparison purpose ,Well it's no a fine solution but it can get you through.

Comment: Well Suraj I tried this join c in dc.COVERS on SqlFunctions.StringConvert(i.CAMPAIGNTYPE).Trim() equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.COV_TYPE).Trim() but this is giving error as well any clues.

Comment: Check the updated answer  , I have tried to convert both values to doubles `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)i.CAMPAIGNTYPE).Trim() equals SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.COV_TYPE).Trim()`

Comment: @Mitz i think this one also not working , well let me check few things .